# Jenkins builds job twice over

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins

I'm a beginner with Jenkins so please go easy.  I have a one Jenkins job setup and am simply passing in one goal as follows: clean test -PregressionTests

...where pregressionTests is configured in Maven POM as follows:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>regressionTests</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/CompleteRegressionSuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now, when I run the Jenkins job (running from CMD line), the suite runs TWICE over with the following message in between:

```
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java" -cp "c:\Jenkins\plugins \maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.4.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1" C:\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.40.jar c:\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.4.jar c:\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.4.jar 63443
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f c:\Jenkins\jobs\JoinOnLine - Complete Regression              Suite\workspace \pom.xml clean test -PregressionTests
```

The build ultimately finishes with 'Finished: Unstable'

I am using maven compiler plugin 3.1 and surefire plugin 2.14.1

I am running Jenkins 1.5.61

I am using Subversion to download the codebase.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I run the Jenkins job (running from CMD line), the suite runs TWICE.

You're running the Jenkins job from the command line? What do you mean by that? Are you running a Maven command as Jenkins would? The command line looks funky. Did you install Maven in Jenkins (Select **Manage Jenkins** from the left hand side, and then go to **Configure System**. You specify Maven installations from there).

Here's what a typical console log output in a Jenkins Maven job looks like:

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace /opt/tomcat/jenkins_home/jobs/keymanagement-trunk/workspace
Updating http://svn.travelclick.net/svn/trunk/KeyManagement at revision '2013-11-08T09:21:09.071 -0600'
U         src/main/java/com/vegicorp/foo/bar.java
At revision 166354
[workspace] $ mvn clean package site
```

See that? It *runs* `mvn` directly. What's going on with your command line? Why are you running `java` and not the `mvn` command? Why the long classpath? Why are you including Jenkins plugins in your command line?